# Can MSMQ raise an event if new message are available

Tags: c#-4.0, msmq

As an alternative to constantly polling an existing Microsoft Messaging Queue, I would like to know if MSMQ by any chance can raise some type of event/notification to let applications know that a message is available?

Comment: Use the ReceiveCompleted event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MessageQueue` has poor notification and hasn't message arrived notification (see [MessageQueue Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4a8520c4))

You could implement notifications yourself. Here is good implementation (see [A simple MSMQ Listener helper class](http://blogs.msmvps.com/manoj/2005/10/16/a-simple-msmq-listener-helper-class/))

Comment: The link is not working, can you please help creating a listener, which invokes when message is recieved.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but came here looking for the event that is hit when a message is received in a queue. Here is what I did:

```
   private static MessageQueue _messageQueue = null;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        if (MessageQueue.Exists(@".\Private$\orders"))
        {
            _messageQueue = new MessageQueue(@".\Private$\orders") {Label = "Testing Queue"};
        }


        _messageQueue.ReceiveCompleted += new ReceiveCompletedEventHandler(OnMessageRecieved);
        _messageQueue.BeginReceive();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static void OnMessageRecieved(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Process your message here. 
        _messageQueue.BeginReceive();
    }
```